# How do you define Truth?

Tags: truth

I know the question has already been shortly answered on this website.
But, I want to specifically know if Tarski's definition of truth is circular or valid?
And if there is any convincingly non-circular definition out there.

It seems obviously circular to me, but it has been pointed out to me that it being circular is not the mainstream view.

We wish to prove the truth of a sentence in the object language (L), but we use a metalanguage (M) to do so, the definition is based around terms used in the sentence of L, but without the notion of "truth".

The whole thing seems circular. I mean not the definition of truth alone, but the usage of the words in the object language and the metalanguage, and the definition of truth taken together. Because, now the words in L are dependent on truth, and truth is now dependent on the same words M.

There is another issue which @Not_here has pointed out. The infinite regression between the meta languages on which to define the notion of truth on.

Comment: @Not_Here: Thanks, I am reading it up currently, as much as I can.

Comment: @Not_Here : That is a major issue as well. The recursion need end somewhere.

Comment: http://www.sa-logic.org/sajl-v1-i1/06-Greimann-SAJL.pdf , I am also reading up on this currently, to get a better grasp on the subject, but wanted a simpler read. Is the paper reliable?

Comment: @Not_Here, Yes, it has to be a valid definition though. You'd have to have a stronger meta language at each regression.

Comment: @Not_Here I don't see how the definition is valid if there is an infinite regression involved. It is adequate though. But in a definition, you do need a starting and an ending point.

Comment: @Not_Here , Yes, I understand. I did not know for sure if there was a circularity. But either there is a circularity, or infinite regression. I thought Tarski must have picked circularity. But, the main concern rests around the definition being valid.

Comment: Then again my ultimate answer is yes it is valid, when you understand the formalism and you understand the actual metamathematics going on behind it you will understand that it is a completely formal and valid process. I'd recommend [Computability and Logic](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/philosophy/logic/computability-and-logic-5th-edition?format=PB&isbn=9780521701464#YXGBVYJ5VPfDqemA.97) as a very accessible textbook that covers what you want to know.

Comment: With that I'll move this [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68266/discussion-between-not-here-and-novice).

Comment: The way 'truth' is defined in Western philosophy is highly arguable, to the point where it seems best to start from scratch. For me call something a truth would require that I know it is true and, as Aristotle notes, this would only be possible where knowledge is identical with its object. Ideas like 'justified true belief' make no sense on my home planet.

Comment: @PeterJ , Yet every object has this property. "The mug is on the desk is true". etc. etc.You are right, knowledge would be required to define truth. What is justified true belief?

Comment: @PeterJ Aristotle essentially subscribed to justified true belief:"*Aletheia, truth, is rather straightforwardly recognized as applicable to mental activity in Aristotle; and specifically, the sorts of mental activity that create links of representation with existing states of affairs in the world.*" What you allude to is closer to Aquinas, but even in him (ideal) knowledge is identical not with the object in the usual sense, but with its form in Creator's mind.

Comment: @Confold - Interpretations vary. Aquinas saw a formal identity, Aristotle something more like a likeness, but it is easy to read the latter as proposing that certain knowledge as lying in the identity of the knower and the object of knowledge. I accept your doubts, however, since yours is the more common view. Maybe I'm reading Aristotle through rose-tinted specs, It remains the case that knowledge cannot be certain without this identity.

Answer (score 1):

If one must rely on Logic or Math to explain the concept of Truth, then it would be a disaster even worse than accepting there's no authentic truths at all.
Fortunately C.S.Peirce has a very intuitive notion:"The opinion which is fated to be ultimately agreed to by all who investigate, is what we mean by the truth..." (http://www.peirce.org/writings/p119.html).
Despite the simplicity of the statement, its meaning is profound and can be generalized to as large as science. There has been no standing still science but one to refute(falsify) others insofar as the investigating community has consensus. They always say about corroboration but that's no more than a method to reach consensus - while the results, by definition, could be as short lived as always.

Circularity is only seen when one tries to explore the absolute truth of everything and so must resort to Logic or Math. Goedle's incompleteness theorem put a barrier in trying to reach such an ideal stage. You have to switch to theology for sure if you willfully must go to the end.